# How to split item of List into two in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a List<> populated like so:

```
ID   mukey      FieldID     Type        PercentOfField  Acres
---------------------------------------------------------------
1   1709649      191        Minor              18       12.5181
2   1709641      191        Minor              1        0.49621
3   1709620      191        Major, Critical    72       49.4322
4   1709622      191        Minor              9        5.89865
```

I would like to take item 3 with Type of Major, Critical and split it into two records with the exact same data except where the Type would be Major for one record and Critical for the other record.  If I loop through the List using foreach, can I split this record into two?

Comment: Are the fields in each tab delimited by tabs?

Comment: Check out the C# split / substring methods. those are probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I formated the table, but removed some detailed bits, hope it's fine. Please post the relevant code. How do you store a record in your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped up this code pretty quick in a console application that should do the trick.... Assuming that you are dealing with a strong type with a definition resembling the following:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Mukey { get; set; }
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int PercentOfField { get; set; }
    public double Acres { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following will do what you are requesting (if I understood the question correctly)

```
var myList = new List<MyObject>()    {
    new MyObject { ID = 1, Mukey = "1709649", FieldID = 191, Type = "Minor", PercentOfField = 18, Acres = 12.5181 },
    new MyObject { ID = 2, Mukey = "1709641", FieldID = 191, Type = "Minor", PercentOfField = 1, Acres = 0.49621 },
    new MyObject { ID = 3, Mukey = "1709620", FieldID = 191, Type = "Minor, Critical", PercentOfField = 72, Acres = 49.4322 },
    new MyObject { ID = 4, Mukey = "1709622", FieldID = 191, Type = "Minor", PercentOfField = 9, Acres = 5.89865 }
};

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    //check if the type is comma delimited
    if (myList[i].Type.Contains(","))
    {
        //get the separate types
        string[] types = myList[i].Type.Split(',');

        var item = myList[i];
        myList.RemoveAt(i);

        //for each type, add a new entry in the list
        foreach (string theType in types)
        {
            myList.Insert(
                i,
                new MyObject
                {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Mukey = item.Mukey,
                    FieldID = item.FieldID,
                    Type = theType.Trim(),
                    PercentOfField = item.PercentOfField,
                    Acres = item.Acres
                }
            );
            // add to i to offset the count for the additional items 
            // (we want to skip the new items)
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like (untested and off the top of my head):

```
var splitList = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Type.Split(", ").Select(t => new myClass(x.ID, x.mukey, x.FieldID, t, x.PercentOfField, x.Acres)).ToList();
```

Of course this makes a new copy of every row in memory, so it's probably not the *best* solution for long tables... Maybe this is better (again untested, but you get the idea):

```
var splitList = myList.SelectMany(x => x.Type.Contains(", ") ? x.Type.Split(", ").Select(t => new myClass(x.ID, x.mukey, x.FieldID, t, x.PercentOfField, x.Acres) : new myClass[] {x}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find any items that have multiple values in that column and remove them and re-add them multiple times, once for each value.  For instance, assuming your list is a list of tab-delimited strings, something like this should work:

```
List<string> records = "...";
foreach (string record in records.ToArray())
{
    string[] fields = record.Split('\t');
    string[] types = fields[3].Split(',');
    if (types.Length > 1)
    {
        records.Remove(record);
        foreach (string type in types)
        {
            fields[3] = type.Trim();
            records.Add(string.Join('\t', fields));
        }
    }
}
```